# How to next or previous in UIScrollview with pagging in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

My problem is: The scrollview has 5 pages, when the global value of current page is 2, I swipe to left or right, it always return to first page. I cannot change next/previous page with the current page. This is my code:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl_Portrait.currentPage = page;
    [self loadDataInChartView:page];

}
```

Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so "`page`" in that above code always stays the same? have you done a "`NSLog(@"page is %d",page);`" to see what it outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the page control only after the UIScrollview has ended scrolling
Make sure paging is enabled for best results

use

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
     self.pageControl_Portrait.currentPage = page;
}
```